# CSS transition-delay longer on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, esp32

I'm trying to build a webpage from which I can control my TV. To show that a button is pressed I have implemented a short transition delay (.1s) during which the button has a different color. This works completely fine on my desktop, but on my mobile phone the transition delay seems to be longer than specified. It looks to be about .2s instead of the specified .1s. Even if the delay is set to 0s it looks to be about the same .2s.

I tested this on my Google Pixel 4a and on an older Huawei both using the Android Chrome browser. On an I-pad using Safari it works as intended.

This (part of) the CSS-code I am using:

```html
<head>
<style>
button {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.button {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .05s;
  transition-delay: .1s;
  box-shadow: .8vw .8vw .8vw black;
}
.button:active {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
  box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <button class="button">
    test_button
  </button>
</div>
</body>
```

I'm "hosting" the webpage from an ESP32, but I don't think that is the problem.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What device and version of its OS are you testing with when you say "on mobile"? Have you tried with different mobile browsers?

Comment: @romkey I did a few more test and added the results to the original question.